# localeChangeInterceptor does not work

Tags: java, spring, localization

I have very standard configuration, I kept editing many times, checked other questions on SO but by my final configuration most people had their issues resolved, however no result for me. Whenever firing requests like:

`http://localhost:8080/appName/?lang=es_MX`

or

`http://localhost:8080/appName?lang=es_MX` it does not resolve to correct locale, it does just do nothing.

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver"></bean>


     <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>
```

I know that default locale resolver by headers work so is my messageResource and .jsp configuration is correct, since I set up one browser explicitly to have es_MX locale and it resolves with AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver correctly.

Does it have to do with the way my handler mappings are defined?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home( Model model, Locale locale, HttpServletRequest hr) {

    String header = hr.getHeader("User-Agent");
    model.addAttribute("header", header);
    String contextPath = hr.getContextPath();
    model.addAttribute("contextPath", contextPath);

    return "index";
}
```

God I spent so much time on this...please help

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by placing interceptor into servlet-context.xml instead of my other config. Now trying to figure it out why in servlet-context.xml it works and in my dedicated config it doesn't, your insights would be valuable ! :-) **I am not accepting my answer, since it does not explain why. Please explain me why this is the case(and so I could test it - ideally resulting in interceptor being placed in my custom config).**

For anyone in trouble try this:

```
<interceptors>
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor"
            p:paramName="lang" />
</interceptors>
```

**inside your servlet-context.xml**

needs namespace:

```
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
```

SessionLocaleResolver seems not to care about location and works in my custom config location too.

Comment: any constrains in the interceptors block? basically anything can be a interceptor then

Answer (score 0):

Check the API docs -> http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/SessionLocaleResolver.html

Also the source of the resolveLocale method of SessionLocaleResolver:

```
public Locale resolveLocale(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Locale locale = (Locale) WebUtils.getSessionAttribute(request, LOCALE_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
    if (locale == null) {
        locale = determineDefaultLocale(request);
    }
    return locale;
}
```

It will in turn get the Locale from the request:

```
protected Locale determineDefaultLocale(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Locale defaultLocale = getDefaultLocale();
    if (defaultLocale == null) {
        defaultLocale = request.getLocale();
    }
    return defaultLocale;
}
```

And in the docs for the ServletRequest.getLocale method:

> Returns the preferred Locale that the client will accept content in,
>   based on the Accept-Language header. If the client request doesn't
>   provide an Accept-Language header, this method returns the default
>   locale for the server. Returns: the preferred Locale for the client

It seems you need to change locale by updating the correct session attribute, which is the job of the LocaleChangeInterceptor.

Maybe something is wrong with the interceptor then. Does it set the locale into the correct LocaleResolver? Can you post the whole spring configuration? Is the mvc namespace correct?

There is a complete i18n tutorial here -> http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internationalization-example/

Comment: how can I verify that? It seems that the interceptor is the problem but again all the config is for interceptor...

Comment: I went through many tutorials, mkyong's is too old, project could not be deployed at least by me, though I resolved dependencies. It is not the first one project of his not to work for me. I guess I am facing very bloody dead-end. So many people have issues with it, horrible.

Comment: Does the interceptor get called at all?

Comment: And most of the config is for the LocaleResolver. Only one section is for the LocaleInterceptor - this one;

Comment: I solved it by placing interceptor into servlet-xml instead my other config. Now trying to figure it out why in servlet-xml it works and in my dedicated config it doesn't, your insights would be valuable ! :-)

Comment: This seems to be almost magical why LocaleInterceptor config does not work in other config location! I defined exactly same component scan package. Hm...